# Multiple conditions in If statement Verilog

Tags: verilog

I have the following if/else  statement :

```
if ((write1 && write 2) && ( read_reg1== read_reg2))
      reg_file[write_reg1] =  write_data1;
    else if((write1 && write 2) && ( read_reg1!=read_reg2)) begin 
      reg_file[write_reg2] =  write_data2;
      reg_file[write_reg1] =  write_data1;
    end
    else if (write1)
      reg_file[write_reg1] =  write_data1;
    else 
      reg_file[write_reg2] =  write_data2;
```

I am getting these errors :

```
ERROR VCP2000 "Syntax error. Unexpected token: 2[_UNSIGNED_NUMBER]. Expected tokens: '[' , '(*' , '(' , 'with' , '++' ... ." "design.sv" 23  28
ERROR VCP2000 "Syntax error. Unexpected token: ). Expected tokens: '(*' , '++' , '--'." "design.sv" 23  58
ERROR VCP2000 "Syntax error. Unexpected token: 2[_UNSIGNED_NUMBER]. Expected tokens: '[' , '(*' , '(' , 'with' , '++' ... ." "design.sv" 25  31
ERROR VCP2000 "Syntax error. Unexpected token: ). Expected tokens: '(*' , '++' , '--'." "design.sv" 25  60
ERROR VCP2000 "Syntax error. Unexpected token: else[_ELSE]. Expected tokens: '#' , ''' , '(' , ';' , '@' ... ." "design.sv" 29  9
```

So what is the problem here ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a space in your variable name.

```
write 2
```

Should be

```
write2
```

Note this occurs twice - in the “if” and the first “else if”

Answer (score 0):

For someone who stumbles upon this question looking for a syntax reference, following are the excerpts from the sections "**4.1.9 Logical operators**" and "**9.4 Conditional statement**" in [one of the revisions of the Verilog standard](https://forums.xilinx.com/xlnx/attachments/xlnx/SYNTHBD/12388/1/Verilog%20-%20LRM.pdf).

This is syntax of **`if` statement**:

```
conditional_statement ::= 
    if ( expression )
        statement_or_null [ else statement_or_null ]
    | if_else_if_statement
```

> If the expression evaluates to true (that is, has a nonzero known value), the first statement shall be executed. If it evaluates to false (has a zero value or the value is `x` or `z`), the first statement shall not execute. If there is
> an else statement and expression is false, the else statement shall be executed.

And this is about **logical operators** to combine multiple conditions in one expression:

> The operators *logical and* (`&&`) and *logical or* (`||`) are logical connectives. The result of the evaluation of a logical comparison shall be `1` (defined as *true*), `0` (defined as *false*), or, if the result is ambiguous, the unknown value (`x`). The precedence of `&&` is greater than that of `||`, and both are lower than relational and equality operators.
>
> A third logical operator is the unary *logical negation* operator (`!`). The negation operator converts a nonzero or true operand into `0` and a zero or false operand into `1`.